# Toro redirects to Wampserver index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, router

I am new to toro and I have the following piece of script in the index page

```
require ('Toro.php');
require ('handlers/SplashHandler.php');
require ('handlers/NewsHandler.php');

ToroHook::add("404", function() {
    echo "Not found";
});

Toro::serve(array(
    "/" => "SplashHandler",
    "/news"=>"NewsHandler"
));
```

and each of the handlers:

```
 class NewsHandler {

    function get() {
        echo 'News page';
    }
 } 



 class SplashHandler {
    function get() {
        echo 'splash page';
    }
 }
```

everything works fine with the SplashHandler with the following url

```
localhost/learning/router
```

but had problem with the newshandler. When I tried the following url:

```
localhost/learning/router/news
```

instead of printing the word "News Page", I was redirected to the wampserver index page. How do I solve this?

this is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try removing '/' in last statement of htaccess. 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: tried removing the '/' but same result, its redirect to wampserver index page